# How do I use cypress with components that are prefetched or preloaded with webpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, cypress, prefetch

I'm using `Cypress` `7.7.0` (also tested on `8.0.0`), and I'm running into an interesting race condition. I'm testing a page where one of the first interactions that `Cypress` does is click a button to open a modal. To keep bundle sizes small, I split the modal into its own prefetched `webpack` chunk. My `Cypress` test starts with `cy.get('#modal-button').click()` but this doesn't load the modal because the modal hasn't finished downloading/loading. It does nothing instead (doesn't even throw any errors to the console). In other words, `Cypress` interacts with the page too quickly. This was also reproduced with manual testing (I clicked on the button super fast after page load). I have tried setting the modal to be preloaded instead, but that didn't work either.

I am able to solve the problem by introducing more delay between page load and button interaction. For example, inserting any `Cypress` command (even a `cy.wait(0)`) before I click on the button fixes the solution. `Cypress`, however, is known for not needing to insert these brittle solutions. Is there a good way to get around this? I'd like to keep the modal in its own chunk.

FYI: I'm using `Vue` as my front end library and am using a simple `defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ './my-modal.vue'))` to load the modal component. I figure that this problem is general to `Cypress` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with waiting for the network to be idle, although there were several options available to me.

The cypress function I used to do this was the following which was heavily influenced by [this solution for waiting on the network](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1773#issuecomment-813812612):

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('waitForIdleNetwork', () => {
    const idleTimesInit = 3
    let idleTimes = idleTimesInit
    let resourcesLengthPrevious

    cy.window().then(win =>
        cy.waitUntil(() => {
            const resourcesLoaded = win.performance.getEntriesByType('resource')

            if (resourcesLoaded.length === resourcesLengthPrevious) {
                idleTimes--
            } else {
                idleTimes = idleTimesInit
                resourcesLengthPrevious = resourcesLoaded.length
            }

            return !idleTimes
        })
    )
})
```

Here are the pros and cons of the solution I went with:

- pros: no need to increase bundle size or modify client code when the user will likely never run into this problem
- cons: technically still possible to have a race condition where the click event happens after the assets were downloaded, but before they could all execute and render their contents, but very unlikely, not as efficient as waiting on the UI itself for indication of when it is ready

This was the way I chose solve it but the following solutions would have also worked:

- creating lightweight placeholder components to take the place of asychronous components while they download and having cypress wait for the actual component to render (e.g. a default modal that just has a spinner being shown while the actual modal is downloaded in the background)

  - pros: don't have to wait on network resources, avoids all race conditions if implemented properly
  - cons: have to create a component the user may never see, increases bundle size
- "sleeping" an arbitrary amount (although this is brittle) with `cy.wait(...)`

  - pros: easy to implement
  - cons: brittle, not recommended to use this directly by Cypress, will cause linter problems if using [eslint-plugin-cypress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-cypress) (you can disable eslint on the line that you use this on, but it "feels ugly" to me (no hate on anyone who programs that way)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with `cy.wait(0)`.

All you are doing is handing control from the test to the next process in the JS queue, in this case it's the app's startup script which is presumably waiting to add the click handler to the button.

I recently found that this is also needed in a React hooks app to allow the hook to complete it's process. You will likely also come across that in Vue 3, since they have introduced a hook-like feature.

If you want to empirically test that the event handler has arrived, you can use the method given here (modified for `click()`) - [When Can The Test Start?](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/)

```js
let appHasStarted

function spyOnAddEventListener (win) {
  const addListener = win.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener
  win.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (name) {
    if (name === 'click') {
      appHasStarted = true
      win.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = addListener  // restore original listener
    }
    return addListener.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

function waitForAppStart() {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const isReady = () => {
      if (appHasStarted) {
        return resolve()
      }
      setTimeout(isReady, 0)  // recheck "appHasStarted" variable
    }
    isReady()
  })
}

it('greets', () => {
  cy.visit('app.html', {
    onBeforeLoad: spyOnAddEventListener
  }).then(waitForAppStart)

  cy.get('#modal-button').click()
})
```

But note `setTimeout(isReady, 0)` will probably just achieve the same as `cy.wait(0)` in your app, i.e you don't really need to poll for the event handler, you just need the app to take a breath.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the solution! I'll try that when I work on my app next! I take it that `cy.wait(0)` isn't as dirty as I think it is? For the sake of throwing out ideas, do you think trying to engineer the button to show a spinner while the component loads is overkill?

Comment: Overkill - the user will never see it in the browser, because the app has the CPU 100% of the time. The problem with Cypress is it's running the test commands as fast as possible and not yielding.

Comment: In Vue terms, `cy.wait(0)` is like `Vue.nextTick()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is that you're already rendering a button before the code backing it is loaded. As you noticed, this isn't only an issue for fast automated bots, but even a "regular" user.

In short, the solution is to not display the button early, but show a loading dialog instead. Cypress allows [waiting for a DOM element to be visible](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-can-I-make-Cypress-wait-until-something-is-visible-in-the-DOM) with even a timeout option. This is more robust than a brittle random wait.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! On that same vein, do you think it would provide a better or worse user experience to show a loading spinner or something on the button while the modal is loading in the background instead of getting rid of the button altogether?

Comment: A small spinner on/in the button seems ideal. Better than a big loading modal that either flickers (when the webpack chunk loads almost instantly) or obnoxiously covers the screen (when the chunk loads slowly or not at all). And like with anything in web development, you do want to give the user a clean sign that something happened or is happening, so your idea sounds good.